# Asymptotic Notation: Does f in o(g) imply g not in O(f)?

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

Does $f \in o(g)$ imply $g \not\in O(f)$?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: And... what... do you think?

Comment: Find some examples to test the claim.

Comment: Some examples will not tell me anything about whether the claim holds in general or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try for instance $f(x)=\ln x$ and $g(x)=x$.  Then $f\in o(g)$.  But $g\not\in O(f)$.

In general,  if $g$ grows faster than $f$, then $g/f$ will "blow up".

Comment: Thank you for your response! Your example is a specific instance for which the implication holds. However, I would like to know whether the implication _always_ holds, for any two functions $f$ and $g$.

Comment: It does.  Because $\frac10=\infty $.